# iframe and JS function combination

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently trying to make a full iframe web-based game to avoid page refresh.

I have this function in JS that works perfect:

```
function changeUrl(){
    var site = "modules/news/news.php";
    document.getElementsByName('game_frame')[0].src = site;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeUrl('news')">News</a>

<iframe frameBorder="0" style="height: width: 100%; height: 650px; visibility: visible; color: white;" allowtransparency="true" class="content" name="game_frame">
</iframe
```

But I would like to fetch a value through the function so that I don't have to repeat the code for every page.

I was trying this but I can't get it to work:

```
function changeUrl(siteName){
    var site = "modules/".siteName."/".siteName.".php";
    document.getElementsByName('game_frame')[0].src = site;
}
```

I have tried for about 2 days to fix this but can't seem to find the solution. I might be googling wrong ofc. Thanks in advance for answers :)

Comment: The string concatenator operator in JS is `+` ...

Comment: There wo go, thanks alot!